# Issue with AngularJS and financial quote

Tags: angularjs, yahoo-finance

I got an issue with my Angular request.

```
angular.module('google-chart-example', []).controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope,$http,$log) {

    $scope.infos = "";

    //$http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com')
    //$http.get('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=TSE:PXT')
    $http.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("AAPL")&format=json')
    .success(function(data) {
            //alert ("toto");
            $scope.infos = data;

    })
    .error(function(data) {
            alert ("data="+data);
        $scope.infos = data;
    });


});
```

$http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com')
==> this is one is working fine .. no trouble

$http.get('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?q=TSE:PXT')
==> This one is not working, i got no result

$http.get('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("AAPL")&format=json')
==> This one, i got an answer but it's telling me the table doesn't exist :
{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quote"}}
(I tried quote ans quotes: same result)

Any idea why I'm not able to retrieve my prices?

My HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"</script>
<script src="index3.js"></script>
 </head>
<body ng-app="google-chart-example" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
coucou <br>
{{infos}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You tring to query yahoo.finance.quotes, however the query need to be on yahoo.finance.quote

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quote
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the yql console to build queries, it'll give you a REST QUERY url that you can use to make http GET requests, for your example:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console

Answer (score 0):

For Yahoo i was missing the community table parameter :
&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

it works now, thanks.