# Why am i getting a 505 error code from the server?

Tags: http, url, https, urlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I looked up the 505 response code and saw that it was "The Web server (running the Web site) does not support, or refuses to support, the HTTP protocol version specified by the client"

The web site I am trying to access on the web server is [https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol %3D"msft"&diagnostics=true&env=store](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20%3D%22msft%22&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

I was able to get on the site and see that it provided xml data. However when I tried to make a HttpsURlConnection with that site, I got a 505 response code, code for doing so is

```
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
HttpsURLConnection httpConnect = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;
int responseCode = httpConnect.getResponseCode();
```

where i inspected the value of params[0]  at runtime and saw that it had the right url in it. Does anyone know how i can fix this issue? The web server should support https because that link works. I don't understand why a 505 error is occuring then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.net.URL` will allow you to create an invalid URL with spaces, which results in this error. Spaces in query parameters should be encoded as `+`, so make your URL:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo+finance.quote+where+symbol+%3D"msft"&diagnostics=true&env=store
```

This request is still incorrect, and will result in a 400 ("expecting table got 'finance'"). From these questions:

- [Getting data from Yahoo Finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795726/getting-data-from-yahoo-finance)
- [Issue with AngularJS and financial quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337392/issue-with-angularjs-and-financial-quote)

I believe you want:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.quote+where+symbol+%3D"msft"&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

Answer (score -1):

I think i got the problem. I looked online and saw that someone else had the problem and that it was the spaces inside the url. I am not sure how to resolve this though